# Unable to run pmd inside java process inside spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest, pmd, static-code-analysis

I want to run pmd inside a java process(created using ProcessBuilder) from within spring as a service.

```
public class PMDService {

  private ProcessBuilder processBuilder;

  private void createProcess() {
    processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    final Map<String, String> envMap = processBuilder.environment();
    String path = envMap.get("Path");
    path += "../../../../../../../static-code-analyzers/pmd/bin;";
    envMap.put("Path", path);
  }


  public String getCommand(PMDParameters params) {
    final StringJoiner command = new StringJoiner(" ");
    command.add("cmd")
    .add("/c")
    .add("pmd")
    .add("-d")
    .add(params.getSourceCodePath())
    .add("-f")
    .add(params.getOutputFormat())
    .add("-R")
    .add(params.getResultSet())
    .add(">")
    .add(params.getResultsPath());

    return command.toString();
  }


  public void runAnalyzer(PMDParameters params) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    createProcess();
    processBuilder.command(getCommand(params));
    final Process process = processBuilder.start();
    process.waitFor();
  }
```

When I test the rest endpoint using postman i get following error :

> ""message": "Cannot run program \"cmd /c pmd -d
>   C:/bootcamp/Spring/springbootcode/springbootdemo -f xml -R
>   rulesets/java/quickstart.xml > .\": CreateProcess error=2, The system
>   cannot find the file specified","

Input json in postman

```
{
   "sourceCodePath": "C:/bootcamp/Spring/springbootcode/springbootdemo",
    "resultsPath": ".",
    "outputFormat": "xml",
    "resultSet": "rulesets/java/quickstart.xml"
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Analysis

In the provided piece of code the program and its arguments are being passed as the **single string value** as the `ProcessBuilder ProcessBuilder.command(String... command)` method parameter.

But that should not be the case: instead, the program and its arguments should be passed separately.

## Solution

Let's use the `ProcessBuilder ProcessBuilder.command(List<String> command)` method.

We will prepare the string list appropriately: it will contain the program and its arguments.

The draft solution:

```java
public List<String> getProgramAndArguments(PMDParameters params) {
    final List<String> programAndArguments = new ArrayList<String>();
    programAndArguments.add("cmd");
    programAndArguments.add("/c");
    programAndArguments.add("pmd");
    programAndArguments.add("-d");
    programAndArguments.add(params.getSourceCodePath());
    programAndArguments.add("-f");
    programAndArguments.add(params.getOutputFormat());
    programAndArguments.add("-R");
    programAndArguments.add(params.getResultSet());
    programAndArguments.add(">");
    programAndArguments.add(params.getResultsPath());
    return programAndArguments;
}

public void runAnalyzer(PMDParameters params) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    createProcess();
    processBuilder.command(getProgramAndArguments(params));
    final Process process = processBuilder.start();
    process.waitFor();
}
```

Additionally, please, make sure that `params.getResultsPath()` has the correct value by providing the correct input: now it is `.`.

Comment: I'm unable to generate the report or locate it 
the service is in `src/main/java/com/gating/staticanalysis/service/PMDService`
and resulPaths I'm providing is `"../../../../../../../reports/pmd_report.xml"`
where report is a folder directly under application

Comment: @pshreyasv, please, take your time to debug the implementation. Additionally, try to use the absolute paths to check that the current implementation is correct. Of course, you may post a separate question to address the new problem.